# Wordpress referring to wrong link after trashing post

Tags: wordpress, redirect, recycle-bin

I have a problem that only started recently on my Wordpress site.

My Wordpress site is in a subfolder like this: https://www.maindomain.com/mysite

After I trash or restore a post, I get redirected to https://www.maindomain.com?trashed=1&ids=9174 (the main domain which is not my website).

I deactivated all plugins and switched to a standard theme, but the problem still occurs.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: How is your url rewrite set up

Comment: I checked my htaccess file and indeed there was a problem with this parameter, problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permalinks issue. Try this:

First go to admin **Settings** and confirm both **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** are `https://www.maindomain.com/mysite`

Then go to **Settings** -> **Permalinks** and hit the **Save Changes** button.